# Android cling device added vs remotedeviceadded

Tags: android, upnp, android-cling

I am using Cling 1.0.5

I am populating view each time `remoteDeviceAdded` is called.

During debug, I see `deviceAdded` is first called, then `remoteDeviceAdded`

Sometimes, `remoteDeviceAdded` is not called up, but `deviceAdded` would still be called.

So which is to use for discovering remote media renderers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, please note that the following pertains to Cling 2.0.1 but I think the logic is the same.

In Cling there's a distinction between a LocalDevice and a RemoteDevice both extending the Device class.
One of the main differences between a LocalDevice and a RemoteDevice is that the RemoteDevice is most likely fully hydrated - all of its service XML definitions are parsed and UPnP actions and states are populated in the RemoteDevice object.

When performing a LAN search for devices, Cling doesn't wait for the discovered Device object to be fully hydrated and calls `localDeviceAdded()` which in turn calls `deviceAdded()`. When this is done, it will call `remoteDeviceDiscoveryStarted()` and attempt to fully hydrate the devices found in the search.
If the device was successfully hydrated, then Cling will call `remoteDeviceAdded()` which in turn calls `deviceAdded()`.
If the device could not be fully hydrated, then Cling will instead call `remoteDeviceDiscoveryFailed()`.

**Just to make it a bit more graphical:**

```
                         Start search
                              +
                              |
                              | Device discovered
                              |
                              v
                            calls
                      LocalDeviceAdded()
                              +
                              |             calls
                              | remoteDeviceDiscoveryStarted()
                              |
                              v
                     Attempt to hydrate
                              +
                              |
                              |
       calls          Success | Failure               calls
remoteDeviceAdded() <---------+---------> remoteDeviceDiscoveryFailed()
```

So now to answer your question, it really depends on what you want to perform in your application:

- If you only need to list basic information about the discovered devices, you can use the LocalDevice you got in `localDeviceAdded()`
- If you need to perform actions with the device, you'll need the RemoteDevice from `remoteDeviceAdded()`.

Personally I would go for a third option where I start operating with the LocalDevice (maybe cache it somewhere, or display it) and wait for the device to become a fully hydrated RemoteDevice to read its state and perform actions.